# How to access an img tag element nested in an h1 tag

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to access the img element that is nested in an h1 element so that I can change the source attribute of the image. However, I can't seem to get the right combination of firstChild, nextSibling, or nextElementSibling.

**NOTE:**The platform I'm using only allows inline styles and script. I can't put functions in the head. The script tag is ignored.

I want to replace the image source when the h1 element is clicked. Here is my code:

```
<div>
    <h1 onclick="(function()
    {
    if(this.nextElementSibling.style.display !== 'none'){
    this.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'none';
    this.innerHTML = '&nbsp;Click';
    console.log(this.nextElementSibling.nodeName);
    console.log(this.firstChild.nodeName);
    }else{
    this.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
    this.innerHTML = '&nbsp;Click';
    console.log(this.firstChild.nodeValue);
    }
    }).call(this);">&nbsp;<img src="r_arrow.png" />Click</h1>

    <div style="display:none; border:solid 1px red;">
    Some hidden content
    </div>
</div>
```

I've used console.log, but I still can't get figure out how to get to that img tag.

Comment: WAT? What kind of platform forces evaluated JS in HTML attribute values. That's whack.

Comment: That is leftover from the way the code previously worked. Form the most part, your solution worked. I just needed to add the setAttribute() method to get change the value of the src attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Your img element is the only child element of the h1, but when you use `this.firstChild` you are likely getting back a reference to the text node that contains `&nbsp;`. To select an actual element you have several options, including:

```
this.querySelector("img").src = "whatever";
this.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src = "whatever";
```

Also, I notice your code includes a line:

```
this.innerHTML = '&nbsp;Click';
```

That will overwrite the existing contents of the h1 element and replace it with that text, i.e., it will delete the img element. Given that both branches of your if/else are setting the `.innerHTML` to the same string I don't think you need that.

Here's a working version of your code:

```
<h1 onclick="(function()
{
var next = this.nextElementSibling,
    img = this.querySelector('img');
if(next.style.display !== 'none'){
  next.style.display = 'none';
  img.src = 'r_arrow.png';
}else{
  next.style.display = 'block';
  img.src = 'some_other_arrow.png';
}
}).call(this);">&nbsp;<img src="r_arrow.png" />Click</h1>
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/kubufexabu/1/edit?html,output

Comment: You're welcome. Mine is basically the same as yours, except I introduced some variables to avoid repeating `this.nextElementSibling` and `this.querySelector` - of course this isn't *necessary* but it makes it easier to read...

Comment: P.S. Note that `.querySelector()` isn't supported in IE7, so if you do need to support IE7 just use `this.getElementsByTagName("img")[0]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Someone tipped me off to querySelector. My code now does what it needs to do.

My final code:

```
<div>
    <h1 onclick="(function()
    {
    if(this.nextElementSibling.style.display !== 'none'){
    this.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'none';
    this.querySelector('img').setAttribute('src','r_arrow.png');
    console.log(this.nextElementSibling.nodeName);
    console.log(this.firstChild.nodeName);
    }else{
    this.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'block';
    this.querySelector('img').setAttribute('src','d_arrow.png');
    }
    }).call(this);">&nbsp;<img src="r_arrow.png" />Click</h1>

    <div style="display:none; border:solid 1px red;">
    Some hidden content
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Someone? That was me, but I deleted my comment and made it an answer. Note that you don't need `.setAttribute()` to set the `src`, you can just say `.src = "something";`